# Programmatically change StartupUri

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xamlparseexception, application-start

I have two windows and dependant upon a condition I want one to be displayed, otherwise I want the other window to be displayed.

this is what I have tried so far.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.CurrentEmailAddress) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.Default.CurrentPassword))
    {
        StartupUri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\FoodExpiryWC\FoodExpiry\FoodExpiry\Views\UserSection\WelcomeScreen.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }
    else
    {
        StartupUri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\FoodExpiryWC\FoodExpiry\FoodExpiry\Views\RegisterViews\MainWindow.xaml");
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting two different errors.

When I use the line

```
StartupUri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\FoodExpiryWC\FoodExpiry\FoodExpiry\Views\UserSection\WelcomeScreen.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

I get the following error

[image: error version1]

When i use the line

```
StartupUri = new Uri(@"C:\Users\User1\Desktop\FoodExpiryWC\FoodExpiry\FoodExpiry\Views\RegisterViews\MainWindow.xaml");
```

I get the following error

[image: error version2]

Is their anyway I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With inspiration from @Jackdaw I have come up with a solution and realised my error.

I was using the absolute path and the IDE didn't like it. I then changed the path to the following

```
StartupUri = new Uri(@"./Views/UserSection/WelcomeScreen.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

The welcome screen constructor took a string parameter so I created a second constructor with no parameter and used the Settings.Default.CurrentEmailAddress

```
public WelcomeScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new WelcomeScreenViewModel(Settings.Default.CurrentEmailAddress);
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be a [Resource File Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#resource-file-pack-uris), like `new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Views/UserSection/WelcomeScreen.XAML")`?